# SSIS package, how to return a success status for main package if one specific component fails

Tags: error-handling, ssis

I want to run SSIS package by SQL Server Agent but I have problem with proper status at the end.
I have main package which contains many containers inside. Most of them is critic and if one of them fail I want to get Failure status inside SSIS package and Job status.
But one of them is not significant and even if it fails I would like to continue the whole process and get success status in the end.

[image: [package schema]]

So like in this picture if Sequence Container 1 fails next container is executed but Sequence Container 3 and whole package get Failure status. I Can't set MaximumErrorCount to 0 in Sequence Container 3 because If Sequence Container or Sequence Container 2 fails I need to see in job history failure

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Event Handler to Sequence Container 3 in the Properties window, find the "EventHandlers" property and click the ellipsis button to open the Event Handler Editor. Then select "OnError" from the "Event Handler Type" dropdown list.
Click Add > In the "Executable" dropdown list, select the SSIS package (the top-level container) > Choose an event handler script task or send an email to alert about the failure, depending on your preference.

Now you need to set the precedence constraints between the containers:

- Connect the green output arrow of Sequence Container 1 to Sequence Container 2.
- Connect the green output arrow of Sequence Container 2 to Sequence Container 3.
- Connect the green output arrow of Sequence Container 3 to the next container or the package's success path.

Don't forget to adjust the MaximumErrorCount property of the Sequence Container 1 and Sequence Container 2 to the desired number (e.g., 1 or 2) to stop the package execution if any of these containers fail.

Finally configure the SQL Server Agent job and make sure that the "Fail job if any step fails" option is selected.

Comment: Thanks Amira for you guidances. I'll try set my package with this way